# Apply regex between two words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need confirm if exists one `\s01\s` between one part of my text, so i kind need a delimiter.

I have this huge text:

```
...

RESUMO DO FECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE : "BRANCO"-RECOLHIMENTO AO FGTS E DECLARAÇÃO À PREVIDÊNCIA 858600000039 672701801102 107527053051 769205500015 Nº ARQUIVO: NmDA0FH71Ig0000-3 Nº DE CONTROLE: BdmBPppCuyu0000-1 INSCRIÇÃO: 57.692.055/0001-27 COMP: 11/2010 COD REC:115 COD GPS: 2100 FPAS: 612 OUTRAS ENT: 3139 SIMPLES: 1 RAT: 3.0 FAP: 1.57 RAT AJUSTADO: 4.71 TOMADOR/OBRA: INSCRIÇÃO: LOGRADOURO: AVENIDA ALEXANDRE COLARES 500 3 ANDAR BAIRRO: VILA JAGUARA CNAE PREPONDERANTE: 4930202 CIDADE: SAO PAULO UF: SP CEP: 05106-000 CNAE: 4930202 CAT QUANT REMUNERAÇÃO SEM 13º REMUNERAÇÃO 13º BASE CÁL PREV SOC BASE CÁL 13º PREV SOC 07 2 1.100,35 429,09 1.100,35 0,00

...
```

And in this particularly piece i need confirm if exists 01 and 07, but if the 01 doesn't exist, the regex is trying to catch in other part of the text, as you can see here: http://regexr.com/3d03m

How could i make the the regex work only between this two words? Is it possible?

Regex: `(?: RESUMO DO FECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE : "BRANCO")(.*? 01 )(?:.*?(?=TOTAIS:))`

Comment: It's not clear to me, what text are you trying to capture?  What is your desired output?

Comment: Could you give an example with a smaller sample? Can't quite grasp what you want.

Comment: In my text, i'm trying to confirm if a 01 and 07 exists between the words RESUMO DO FECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE : "BRANCO" and the first TOTAL:, the problem is, i have other TOTAl in the text, so if the 01 doesn't exist between this words, the regex will try to match with the next TOTAL.

Comment: So, the text in the demo should not be matched at all? Try to replace all `.*?` with `(?:(?!TOTAIS:).)*`. This is not the best solution though, an unrolled version is preferable (`.*?` --> `[^T]*(?:T(?!OTAIS:)[^T]*)*`).

Comment: Yes! Now is working, could you explain to me, please? And.. it is a unrolled version??

Comment: And post as answer, please @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that `.*?` - though called "lazy" or "reluctant" - still tries to match as many characters as it can to return a valid match. As `.` matches any character but a newline, it matches your leading multicharacter delimiter (and trailing, too).

If you had 1 char delimiters, like `[` or `]`, you would use a *negated character class* `[^\]\[]*` instead of `.*?`. Here, you may use a tempered greedy token:

```
(?:(?!TOTAIS:).)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD0tH8/3)

To support multiline text, `.` must be replaced with `[\s\S]`.

However, this solution is rather resource consuming as we basically check each position, if it starts the sequence of `TOTAIS:`, we stop matching. A more efficient approach is to unroll this token, say, as:

```
[^T]*(?:T(?!OTAIS:)[^T]*)*
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD0tH8/2)

This version matches across newlines, too. It matches 0* characters other than `T` and then 0* sequences of a `T` that is not followed with `OTAIS:` followed with 0* occurrences of characters other than `T`. However, it cannot check if `TOTAIS` is a whole word.

Comment: I am busy right now, but if anything is unclear, please drop a comment, I will answer in half an hour.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Comment: What is a tempered greedy token? :B.

Comment: Here is some explanation of the [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed). It is based on a dot matching with a negative lookahead that prevents overflowing the delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do.. sorry..
But based on what your title "apply regex between two words,"
I assume, if "01" and "07" comes, you want to put comma between. 
If that's the case, then it will be: (Perl)

s/(01)\s+(07)/\1,\2\3/g;

Comment: i want confirm if exists between the words RESUMO DO FECHAMENTO - EMPRESA MODALIDADE : "BRANCO"  and TOTAL like i said @Gon, not in the whole text.